# significant evolution

Tags: statistical-significance, trend

I know the number of customers who come every day into a shop. I need to calculate the evolution of the number of customers over two year (2801 customers in 2018, 2999 customers in 2019 -> 7% of evolution).

My problem is that I am asked if the evolution is significant. For me it does not make sense because we do not have data of samples but of the whole population, so there is no need for a test : there are more customers in 2019 than in 2018, it is a fact.

However, I thought I could take into account the number of customers per day (and not per year), and then perform a paired t-test (to answer the question : Is the daily number of customers in 2019 significatly more important in 2019 than in 2018). Do you think it is a correct way to answer the question ?

I guess this is a very basic question but I am lost about it. Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: As you said, if you have data for the whole population there is no point in doing inference. There is a 7 % increase. Whether that is significant is up to you to decide. Maybe you should ask for an elaboration of "significant".

Comment: I'll assume by "significant" they mean "statistically significant".  Otherwise, you might think of "significant" in a more general sense, and maybe compare the 7% growth to say growth in the industry across the region.

Comment: If you are forced to present a p-value, I would probably use the total counts and compare them to 0.50/0.50 proportions with a binomial test or a chi-square goodness-of-fit test.  I like the paired *t* test idea too, though it's not necessarily answering a question about the total counts.  That is, if the day-to-day variability is high, you might not get good signal-to-noise, but that doesn't undermine the 7% increase.